# New-Item executed even though it's within an 'if' statement

Tags: powershell

I created a script to pull JPEG snapshots from 2 IP cameras. For me to keep them organized I added some lines to check the date and create a folder matching it. The script also checks if the folder exists and if it does, should skip to the snapshot capture.

Everything works fine as intended but it seems for one reason or another the script still tries to create the folder and shows and error in my PS console that the directory exists.

```
$chk_path = Test-Path "C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
$Make_SnapShot_Folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
$Camera_A = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://10.0.0.132/snap.jpeg',"C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))\Camera_A$((Get-Date).ToString('HH-mm-ss')).jpeg")
$Camera_B = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://10.0.0.132/snap.jpeg',"C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))\Camera_B$((Get-Date).ToString('HH-mm-ss')).jpeg")
if (-not ($chk_path) ) {
write-host "C:\SnapShots doesn't exist, creating it"
$Make_ScrapShot_Folder
} else {
write-host "C:\SnapShots exists, Saving SnapShots"
}
Camera_A
Camera_B
```

Comment: You're trying to create the path before checking it if exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other languages probably you've used, PowerShell will execute the code when you *assign* it to a variable not when the variable is *called*.

So you're actually creating the folder with this line:

```
$Make_SnapShot_Folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
```

You just can re-arrange your code to make it do what you want, and to be more efficient:

```
$day = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$snapshots_dir = "C:\SnapShots\$day"

if (Test-Path $snapshots_dir) {
    Write-Host "$snapshots_dir exists, Saving SnapShots"
} else {
    Write-Host "$snapshots_dir doesn't exist, creating it"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $snapshots_dir
}

$timestamp = Get-Date -Format 'HH-mm-ss'

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://10.0.0.132/snap.jpeg',"$snapshots_dir\Camera_A$timestamp.jpeg")
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://10.0.0.132/snap.jpeg',"$snapshots_dir\Camera_B$timestamp.jpeg")
```

Comment: Thanks James! This is just want I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should work:

```
$str_path = "C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
$chk_path = Test-Path $str_path
if ($chk_path) {
    $Make_SnapShot_Folder = Get-Item -Path $str_path
} else {
    $Make_SnapShot_Folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $str_path
}
$Make_SnapShot_Folder      ### this outputs a DirectoryInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
$Make_SnapShot_Folder = 
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\SnapShots\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
```

To here:

```
if (-not ($chk_path) ) {
<-- Here
write-host "C:\SnapShots doesn't exist, creating it"
$Make_ScrapShot_Folder <-- Remove this line
```